# Phylogenetic analysis software (BAMM) error message tells me my phylogeny has non-positive branch lengths. I changed this but the error remains

Tags: phylogeny

My phylogeny is one from a publication, and is a consensus tree from BEAST, which is known to introduce non-positive branch lengths.  I've checked the phylogeny for "-" and "0," which should reveal non-positive branch lengths and found a zero-length one which I altered to 0.0000001.  However, this seems not to have solved my problem.
Is there a function to sanity check a given phylogeny, e.g. check for such branch lengths and alter them, check for singletons, etc.  The tree is fully bifurcating so I don't need to check that again.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell where your problem actually stems from without a reproducible example but from what you're telling, it could come from adding the 0.0000001 that makes the tree non ultrametric anymore (all the descendents from the +0.0000001 branch are that longer than the others). You could try to solve this problem using the `dispRity::remove.zero.brlen` function:

```
library(ape)
library(dispRity)
## Creating a random ultrametric tree
set.seed(1)
tree <- ape::rcoal(10)

## Introducing a zero branch length
tree$edge.length[17] <- tree$edge.length[17] + tree$edge.length[15]
tree$edge.length[16] <- tree$edge.length[16] + tree$edge.length[15]
tree$edge.length[15] <- 0

## Checking ultrametricity
ape::is.ultrametric(tree)
# [1] TRUE

## Checking zero branch lengths
any(tree$edge.length == 0)
# [1] TRUE
```

The method you're using removes the ultrametric property of the tree:

```
## Adding a really small branch length (does not conserve ultrametricity)
tree_bad <- tree
tree_bad$edge.length[15] <- 0.0000001

## Checking ultrametricity
ape::is.ultrametric(tree_bad)
# [1] FALSE

## Checking zero branch lengths
any(tree_bad$edge.length == 0)
# [1] FALSE
```

You can use `dispRity::remove.zero.brlen` instead that adds 1% of the minimum branch length but conserves the tree properties:

```
tree_good <- tree

## Removing zero branch lengths
tree_good <- dispRity::remove.zero.brlen(tree_good)

## Checking ultrametricity
ape::is.ultrametric(tree_good)
# [1] TRUE

## Checking zero branch lengths
any(tree_good$edge.length == 0)
# [1] FALSE
```